# SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Cancel

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, asynchronous, ado.net

Is there any way to run `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` asynchronously and then cancel it (on the server side as well) whilst it's being executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET Framework 4.5 has a ExecuteScalarAsync() method.
See here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalarasync(v=vs.110).aspx

ExecuteScalarAsync() also has an overload with a CancellationToken parameter that can be used to abandon the operation before the command timeout elapses.